# How to avoid or minimize the bundle received as null while making a connection; GoogleApiclient android

Tags: android, location, google-api-client

I am trying to regularly listen for updates in location in my android app.

Here is my code to build the google api client

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    createLocationRequest();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}
```

here is the createLocationRequest() code :

```
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(0);
    mLocationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(0);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(0);

    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}
```

here is the startlocationupdate() :

```
protected void startLocationUpdates() {

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}
```

this is onConnected(Bundle hint):

```
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        startLocationUpdates();
}
```

However, this works fine like 80% of the times but sometimes it just doesn't work.
I receive hint as null on connection and then location updates just don't come. There is no particular device on which it is happening.

For instance, today morning on one device os 5.1 it was working fine, and on a same model and os device, it just didn't run.

Please let me know if I am missing something or if I need to add something else to avoid this problem

Comment: If someone can tell me whether we can improve our device' location using the device sensors or not ? If yes, then can you please help me understand how we can achieve this.